# How to copy public folder from src to dist folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, glob

I try to copy the public folder with gulp to the dist folder but it doesnt copy the structure right , any idea what am I doing wrong here ?

```
gulp.task('copy', () => {
    return gulp
        .src(['./src/config.json', './src/**/*.jade','./src/public/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This is the public structure

[image]

it copy all the folder inside the public folder **under the root of dist** without the **public** folder , how can I copy it as is (public and all sub files and folders as is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should copy all the files & folders within *src*:

```
gulp.task('copy', () => {
  return gulp
    .src('src/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/dist/from/gulpfile'));
});
```

Make sure the gulpfile is located at the same level as *src*. And the path to *dest* should be relative from the gulpfile.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy public files in different task and set base directory in gulp.src:

```
gulp.task('copy_public', () => {
    return gulp
        .src(['./src/public/**/*'], {base: "./src/public"})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```